# How to add voice recognition into fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, voice-recognition

I'm working on app and I'm trying to add voice recognition into fragment to give the user an option to scroll the pages from left to right and click on button and use voice recognition. But the problem is: when I extend from Fragment, in onActivityResult I cannot initialize TextView, and RESULT_OK. When I extend from FragmentActivity, it's underscore onCreateView.

Which extend should I use to get the result I want to get?

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_1_fragment_1, container, false);

        ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.voiceRecognition1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

        final TextView frag1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag_1_frag_1);
        final TextView frag1ru = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag_1_frag_1_ru);

        frag1ru.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (frag1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                    frag1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    frag1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {//RESULT_OK become red
            ArrayList<String> results;
            results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);//findViewByID become red
            String str="";
            for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
                str+= results.get(i);
            }
            if (str.equals("five")) {
                speechText.setText(str);
            }else{
                speechText.setText("It's not: " + str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the things in footer of Activity which consumes this fragment, call button action on it

Comment: Thank's for your attention to my post! I changed the code and description.